# Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Points $D$ and $E$ are located on side $BC$ such that $\angle BAD=\angle DAE=\angle EAC.$ Prove that $AB=AC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

This is a very interesting word problem that I came across in an old textbook of mine. So I know its got something to do with circle geometry, which yields the shortest, simplest proofs, but other than that, the textbook gave no hints really and I'm really not sure about how to approach it or draw the diagram. Any guidance hints or help would be truly greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :) So anyway, here the problem goes:

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Points $D$ and $E$ are located on side $BC$ such that $\angle BAD=\angle DAE=\angle EAC.$ Suppose that the circumcircles of triangles $ABD$ and $AEC$ both pass through the circumcentre of triangle $ABC$.
>
> (a) Prove that $AB=AC$.
>
> (b) Find the exact value of $\angle BAC$.

[image]

Comment: I added a diagram for clarity, I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Wow thank you very much good sir! Edit: Does a diagram also exist for where centre O is below triangle?

Comment: The solution is actually given by an acute and isosceles triangle, so we do not have to worry about that configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the circumcenter of $ABC$, and $\widehat{BAC}=3\alpha$, $\widehat{CBA}=\beta$, $\widehat{BCA}=\gamma$.
Since $O$ lies on the circumcircle of $BAD$ we have
$$ 2\gamma = \widehat{AOB} = \widehat{ADB} = \pi-(\alpha+\beta) $$
and in a similar way
$$ 2\beta = \widehat{AOC} = \widehat{AEC} = \pi-(\alpha+\gamma) $$
so by subtracting the last two equations term-by-term we get $2(\gamma-\beta)=(\gamma-\beta)$, from which $\gamma=\beta$ and $AB=AC$ follow. The exact value of $\alpha$ can be recovered from $\widehat{AOB}=\widehat{ADB}$, implying $\pi-3\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}$, $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{7}$ and $\widehat{BAC}=\color{red}{\large \frac{3\pi}{7}}\approx 77^\circ 8' 34''$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2}{3}\alpha+\gamma=\measuredangle BDA=\measuredangle BOA=2\gamma,$$
which gives $\gamma=\frac{2}{3}\alpha$.

By the same way we can get that $\beta=\frac{2}{3}\alpha$ and from here $AB=AC$.

Since $2\cdot\frac{2}{3}\alpha+\alpha=180^{\circ}$, we obtain: $\alpha=\frac{540^{\circ}}{7}$.